# Feature flag for `std::invoke_result`

Tags: c++, g++, c++17, language-features

Over at [gnu.org](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/status.html#status.iso.2017), a list of features flags are given for various C++17 features is provided. However, I cannot find a feature flag for support of `std::invoke_result`. How can I tell if a particular version of `g++` supports `std::invoke_result`?

Note: I would also like to find flags to determine support for `std::invoke_result` in Visual Studio and Clang's `libstdc++`, as I couldn't find those either.

Comment: `#if __cplusplus >= 201703L`?

Comment: Visual Studio in particular is reluctant to include these macros as they are only listed in a working paper and not officially standardized. Instead they have their own [non-standard list](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2017/12/19/c17-progress-in-vs-2017-15-5-and-15-6/) of features implemented.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: That worked for g++-6.4, but not for clang-902.0.39.1.

Comment: Did you remember to enable C++17? Maybe Xcode doesn't enable it by default yet?

Comment: I don't use Xcode. I use a makefile, and it has C++17 enabled with `--std=c++1z`.

Comment: Then that's your problem. "C++1z" is not C++17 (even though it might be close), so `__cplusplus` can't report that the compiler supports C++17. Unless specified otherwise (you can [read the last draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/n4659.pdf) yourself) then the only *portable* way to check for feature existence is through `__cplusplus` and its value.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: I used that same flag on g++-6.4.0, which works. It doesn't work because `__cplusplus >= 201703L` evaluates to true, then hits the `std::invoke_result`, which is not supported, and the compile fails.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: Same thing happens with `-std=c++17`.